# Bazel cannot find custom CPU constraint_value added in toolchain

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to add an armv6k cpu constraint value to https://github.com/grailbio/bazel-toolchain to create a platform and cross compile for the raspberry pi zero. I'm using this toolchain in another project to compile both on x86-64 and cross compile for the pi (bare minimum test case linked below).

I have this defined in the platforms/BUILD.bazel in my branch of the above repo:

```
constraint_value(
    name = "armv6k",
    constraint_setting = "@platforms//cpu:cpu",
)
```

Which, as I understand the platform docs, should add a "@platforms//cpu:armv6k".

When I define the platform like this (in the same file):

```
platform(
    name = "linux-armv6k",
    constraint_values = [
        "@platforms//os:linux",
        "@platforms//cpu:armv6k",
    ],
)
```

I run into this error:

```
ERROR: /home/ubuntu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_1000/a08c2e4811c846650b733c6fc815a920/external/com_grail_bazel_toolchain/platforms/BUILD.bazel:38:9: no such target '@platforms//cpu:armv6k': target 'armv6k' not declared in package 'cpu' defined by /home/ubuntu/.cache/bazel/_bazel_1000/a08c2e4811c846650b733c6fc815a920/external/platforms/cpu/BUILD (did you mean 'armv7k'? Tip: use `query "@platforms//cpu:*"` to see all the targets in that package) and referenced by '@com_grail_bazel_toolchain//platforms:linux-armv6k'
```

I expected that @platforms//cpu:armv6k would be a valid declaration with the constraint_value present. `bazel query @platforms//cpu:*` should show armv6k, but it does not.

A bare minimum test case is here: https://github.com/baverbud/armv6k-testcase

Full set of changes to the grailbio toolchain (used by the bare minimum test case above) are here: https://github.com/baverbud/bazel-toolchain-raspi/tree/linux-armv6k

Environment details:

```
ubuntu@0a6fc3f137a5:/src/workspace$ bazel info release
release 6.2.1
```

Building using the gcr.io/bazel-public/bazel:latest linux docker image as of today (July 11, 2023) (host machine is windows).

Relevant web searches:
I found https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/13047 which looks like it could be related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//platforms:armv6k` is a label referring to your new `constraint_value`, use that instead. `@platforms//cpu:armv6k` is looking in the `@platforms//cpu` package, which you haven't modified, so it's not there.

You could also write `@com_grail_bazel_toolchain//platforms:armv6k` to fully qualify the label. Because it's in the same package in this case, `:armv6k` also works.

For reference, you can inspect what's in that package via the convenience symlink in your workspace directory at `bazel-out/../../../external/platforms/cpu/BUILD`. I find that helpful for debugging.